# How do you update a NuGet package from a custom package source in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

Our company has its own NuGet repository for common libraries used in many applications.

In Visual Studio 2013, it's very simple to update the package, just click the "Update" or "Update All" button:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 NuGet Interface]

In Visual Studio 2015, I can't find a way to update the package:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 NuGet Interface]

The dropdown doesn't give an update option, just install/uninstall.

[image: Dropdown Options from VS2015]

I did notice the "Update" option is available when updating packages from nuget.org or "Microsoft and .NET," but it doesn't appear for any of our internal packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with Visual Studio 2015.  Upgrading to Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 solves the issue and provides a new "Update" button interface that works with local packages.